# How to delay closing tkinter window after button click?

Tags: tkinter, delay, destroy

I've got a simple tkinter gui that displays a radio button and  ok cancel buttons. When the ok button is clicked I want to get on with running my program, then 5 seconds later have the window close.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import *

gui = tk.Tk()

gui.geometry('330x150')
# set up radio buttons
selected = tk.IntVar()  # selected holds radio button currently selected


def ok_clicked():

    gui.after(5000, lambda : gui.destroy())

    #run stuff while waiting for the gui to close
        if selected.get() == 0:
             # run HS
             import Open_HS
         else:
             # run KA
             import Open_KA

def cancel_clicked():
    gui.destroy()

hs_btn = Radiobutton(gui, width=15, text="Radio 1", value=0,variable=selected).place(x=50, y=40)
ok_btn = Button(gui, width=9, text="OK", command=ok_clicked).place(x=180, y=115)
cancel_btn = Button(gui, width=9, text="Cancel", command=cancel_clicked).place(x=250, y=115)

gui.mainloop()
```

This obviously doesn't work because I'm calling

```
gui.mainloop.
```

before I set up the delay with

```
gui.after(5000, lambda : gui.destroy())
```

but how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you say _"This obviously doesn't work"_? It works for me. When I click the button, the window is destroyed after 5 seconds.

Comment: Hmm it does when I try too now. But it doesn't in my actual code which contains an import instruction to import a separate file immediately below the .after command. I've edited the code to show what I mean. Sorry I didn't think that was the problem so left it out before.

Comment: Your code won't run as posted since you are importing custom modules. You need to include the smallest possible implementation of `Open_HS`   that causes the problem.

Comment: Ok thanks for that. I understand now. I thought the problem was in the code snippet I posted but I see now it's in my Open_HS module. I'ts going to take a while to work through it. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I had a look in the code that followed and placed the gui.destroy() line after the part that was locking up execution  (selenium webdriver) and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Using `gui.after` can achieve what you need:

```
import tkinter as tk


def ok_clicked():
    gui.after(5000, gui.destroy)


def cancel_clicked():
    gui.destroy()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    gui = tk.Tk()

    gui.geometry('330x150')
    selected = tk.IntVar()

    tk.Radiobutton(gui, width=15, text="Radio 1", value=0, variable=selected).place(x=50, y=40)
    tk.Button(gui, width=9, text="OK", command=ok_clicked).place(x=180, y=115)
    tk.Button(gui, width=9, text="Cancel", command=cancel_clicked).place(x=250, y=115)

    gui.mainloop()
```